# Overfitting small dataset necessary for deep NNs when training with big dataset works?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, overfitting, batch-normalization

In the [CS231n](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/) course from Standford, they state that a network should be able to overfit a small dataset by getting zero cost, otherwise it is not worth training.

However, what if a network is not able to overfit a small dataset (i.e. $cost \geq \lambda \gg 0$) but the network converges to $\mu > \lambda$ with a large dataset which is a good cost value for the application at hand? I have a similar situation (with the difference that I am using BatchNorm which may prevent convergence to 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BatchNorm should not keep your model from overfitting, otherwise there's something wrong with your BatchNorm.
If you can't overfit on a small dataset, there's something wrong with your network or training and you likely could get better performance on the large dataset after fixing those issues.